# googlemock - mock a method that returns a complex datatyp

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I want to mock a method that returns a complex datatyp

```
class aClass
{
public:
   virtual const QMap<QString, QString> aMethod() const;
}

class MockaClass : public aClass
{
public:
   MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(aMethod, const QMap<QString, QString>());
}
```

This code does not compile: "macro "MOCK_CONST_METHOD0" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2"

I think that the googlemock macro does not understand QMap and interpret the comma as parameter separator.

Is there a way to tell googlemock that QMap is the return value?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use a `typedef` like this:

```
class aClass
{
public:
   typedef const QMap<QString, QString> MyType;
   virtual MyType aMethod() const;
}

class MockaClass : public aClass
{
public:
   MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(aMethod, MyType());
}
```

Comment: Errrrm, shouldn’t that be `MOCK_CONST_METHOD1`, since it takes one parameter?  (good solution, though)

Comment: @Mawg: `aMethod` has zero parameters, therefore `MOCK_CONST_METHOD0`should be correct.

Comment: Aaargh!! I mis-read ... how embarrassing. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 4):

You are right, the comma is interpreted as a parameter separator. You can define a preprocessor macro to protect the comma from being interpreted that way.

```
#define COMMA ,
MOCK_CONSTANT_METHOD0(aMethod, const QMap<QString COMMA QString>());
```

Please note, that this will not necessarily work for nested macro calls. For example, if `MOCK_CONSTANT_METHOD0` would pass the second parameter to another macro, you would be in trouble again.

Comment: Why does introducing this `define` avoid the compiler error? The resulting code (after preprocessing) is the same as in the question. Could you explain, why this works?

Comment: @RonaldMcBean I do not know why this works, but it seems like the preprocessor extracts the parameters first and then expands the macros in them.

Comment: [see this answer for an explanation why it works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10208278/913577)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `()` for complex param,

```
class MockaClass : public aClass
{
public:
   MOCK_METHOD((const QMap<QString, QString>), aMethod, (), (const));
}
```